# Sigsuspend system call issue

Tags: c, signals, system-calls, flags, suspend

```
sigfillset(&set);
sigdelset(&set, SIGUSR2);

sigsuspend(&set);

// signal handler sets a flag

if(flag == 1)
    //do something
```

In this case, my thread only wakes up when a SIGUSR2 is delivered.
However, it seems that something else forces sigsuspend to return, but i don't know what since all other signals are masked.
Is there any problem in this code fragment?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please show us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell what exactly is wrong without seeing the rest of the code, but there is at least one problem with the code you show:

Before returning, `sigsuspend(2)` restores the signal mask that was active when it was called. If you didn't change the process's signal mask accordingly before calling `sigsuspend(2)`, then there is a window of time between returning from `sigsuspend(2)` and testing the value of `flag` where other pending signals may be delivered (or it may even be the case that new signals are generated and delivered). If these signals are caught and the handler changes the value of `flag` to another value, you "lose" the update that the handler of `SIGUSR2` did.

For example, consider this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t flag;

void handler1(int signo) {
    printf("In handler1\n");
    flag = 1;
}

void handler2(int signo) {
    printf("In handler2\n");
    flag = 2;
}

int main(void) {
    struct sigaction sigact;
    sigact.sa_handler = handler1;
    sigact.sa_flags = 0;
    sigfillset(&sigact.sa_mask);

    if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sigact, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("sigaction()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sigact.sa_handler = handler2;

    if (sigaction(SIGUSR2, &sigact, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("sigaction()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sigset_t mask;
    sigfillset(&mask);
    sigdelset(&mask, SIGUSR1);

    sigsuspend(&mask);

    printf("%d\n", flag);

    return 0;
}
```

It catches `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`, blocks every signal except `SIGUSR1`, and then calls `sigsuspend(2)`.

Run it, and then send it `SIGUSR2` followed by `SIGUSR1`. This ensures that there is a signal pending before `SIGUSR1` is seen and acted upon. It also causes `SIGUSR2` to be delivered as soon as `SIGUSR2` is unblocked, which happens after `sigsuspend(2)` returns (because we didn't touch the process's signal mask):

```
filipe@filipe-Kubuntu:~/dev$ kill -SIGUSR2 29755
filipe@filipe-Kubuntu:~/dev$ kill -SIGUSR1 29755
```

Output:

```
filipe@filipe-Kubuntu:~/dev$ ./a.out 
In handler1
In handler2
2
```

How do you fix it? Just make sure that the process's signal mask is set to the same mask as you use in `sigsuspend(2)` so that it doesn't mistakenly restore the mask. This is as simple as adding this before calling `sigsuspend(2)`:

```
if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, NULL) < 0) {
    perror("sigprocmask()");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

So, the updated program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t flag;

void handler1(int signo) {
    printf("In handler1\n");
    flag = 1;
}

void handler2(int signo) {
    printf("In handler2\n");
    flag = 2;
}

int main(void) {
    struct sigaction sigact;
    sigact.sa_handler = handler1;
    sigact.sa_flags = 0;
    sigfillset(&sigact.sa_mask);

    if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sigact, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("sigaction()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sigact.sa_handler = handler2;

    if (sigaction(SIGUSR2, &sigact, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("sigaction()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sigset_t mask;
    sigfillset(&mask);
    sigdelset(&mask, SIGUSR1);

    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("sigprocmask()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sigsuspend(&mask);

    printf("%d\n", flag);

    return 0;
}
```

This works as expected: it is guaranteed that no other signal handlers will execute between the window of time after `sigsuspend(2)` returns and you test `flag`.

Another important note: I don't know how you set up the signal handler, but if you're using `signal(2)`, then don't: its semantics are platform-dependent and it may not behave as you want. You should use `sigaction(2)` exactly as I show in the sample program. The line `sigfillset(&sigact.sa_mask)` is needed to make sure that when the signal handler is running, all other signals are still blocked - otherwise, delivery of a signal in the midst of executing `SIGUSR1`'s handler could invoke another handler that changed the flag.